# Fixing JS errors in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery for my app and I'm getting this error in IE:

```
Line: 13
Char: 9
Error: Expected Identifier, string or number
Code: 0
```

..well, as you can see, the error isn't quite helpful. How do you fix those weird IE errors? Is there any tool or a list of error descriptions that tells you what to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Oh no, don't tell me ... is is IE6? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest looking at line 13 of your JS file to find out where the error is.

FWIW, the "Expected Identifier, string or number" error often occurs when you have a trailing comma in a list or object declaration. Firefox doesn't mind this, but IE does.

Comment: Exactly, it was an extra comma! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article on [debugging javascript in IE](http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html). IE8 comes with a [built-in debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The [IE Script debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Script_Debugger) is quite OK.

But try Mozilla's error console first. It has sane line numbering. Maybe the errors are identical.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have Microsoft Office installed
- In IE, go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced tab
- From there UNCHECK "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)"
- Then when a script creates an error, you will be presented with a dialog box:

[image: Script error in IE]

Click the YES button <del>to sign your life over to microsoft</del> to start the debugger.

This is a really tedious workflow (the default sound that happens when a script bug is encountered is *really* annoying) so I don't think its a good way to work, recommend firefox error console over it any day.

[See also](http://web.archive.org/web/20070403183550/http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html).